# How to get NSAttributedString for a giving size?

Tags: ios, uitextview, core-text, nsattributedstring

I'm currently writing an iOS 6 only app that will work in a similar way to iBooks. I have a large text inside a NSAttributedString and want to split it into pages.

Each page have a UITextView that will be responsible for presenting the text. I'm using UITextView instead of CoreText because I want to have text selection so the user can highlight the text.

**Here is my problem:** I want to be able to split the "full" NSAttributedString into pages that will be the size of my UITextView.

Unfortunately on iOS 6, UITextView draws the NSAttributedString in a different way than CoreText. So, using CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange is not an option.

Does anyone know a way to get an NSAttributedString for a specific size that is not brute force?

Thanks,

Abras

Comment: Sorry I only have a walk around solution. You can split the text before you init the `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: But this wouldn't work. How will you split the text before NSAttributedString if the string will change its size after the attributes?